# Wrong timestamp in log4j XMLLayout

Tags: java, logging, log4j, appender, rollingfileappender

I set my log4j configuration to use two appenders (ConsoleAppender and RollingFileAppender) the ConsoleAppender is using this layout (PatternLayout: ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n) and the RollingFileAppender is using XMLLayout. So the problem is that the ConsoleAppender output is displaying the correct date when I log an error, let's say "05/28/2010 12:45 PM" but the XMLLayout timestamp attribute is being set 5 hours into the future, when I convert that epoch value to DateTime I got "05/28/2010 5:45 PM". I even used http://www.epochconverter.com/ to check if my conversion algorithm was wrong and the result was the same. Any idea why is this happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like one conversion is respecting UTC offset and one (the one in the future) is not.  You're in the EDT timezone, correct?